# Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook) on opening file with named range

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I've just started working with XSSF library in .xlsm files and pretty new in this. I'm facing an issue in .xlsm reading and writing.
I'm getting the following message when trying to open the written file

> Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

I've posted my code below

```
    String fileName = "C:\\Ishan\\Test.xlsm";
    String fileName2 = "C:\\Ishan\\Test4.xlsm";
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
     XSSFWorkbook workbook=null;
     String[] dropDownList =  new String[5];
     dropDownList[0]="1";
     dropDownList[1]="2"; dropDownList[2]="3";
     dropDownList[3]="4"; dropDownList[4]="5";

    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(fin)
        );


        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");

        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
        if(row == null)
             row = sheet.createRow(0);

        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
        if(cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(0);

        row = sheet.createRow(0);
        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue("Hello");

        XSSFName name = workbook.createName();
        name.setNameName("data");

         fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName2));
        workbook.write(fout);
        fout.close();
        System.out.println("xlsm created successfully..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(fout!=null){
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
                fout = null;
            }
            if(workbook!=null){
                workbook = null;
            }
            if(fin!=null){
                fin.close();
                fin = null;
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

I've not even started to use the named range for any purpose, just created. What can be the issue and what approach I can take to rectify ?
I'm using Apache POI v3.8.

Comment: "I've not even started to use the named range for any purpose, just created": But not properly created. A `Name` needs at least a formula which it refers to. Else it will be removed as you see. See [Named Ranges and Named Cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Named+Ranges+and+Named+Cells).

Comment: @AxelRichter : Thank you :) . It worked now. I'll keep in mind this point :)